# How to transition e.g. fade, from one view controller to another

Tags: xcode, button, segue, viewcontroller

I have done a lot of research on Youtube, websites and Stack Overflow, but couldn't find anything that worked. Hopefully, you can help me. I have view controllers in Xcode, and buttons on them that perform segues, to show the next view controller. But when it changes view controllers with the button performing a segue (show), it brings the next view controller up from the bottom of the screen. How do I change the transition (or add a transition) to make them fade into each other.

Comment: Your question would be easier to understand if you add the important parts of your source code. You can edit your question any time!

Answer (score 1):

What you’re doing(the segue) is presenting the view modally. This is an Apple defined behavior which we get for free.

What you want is a custom view controller transition. Therefore you’ll need to implement it yourself.

Luckily, Apple has a great system built-in that makes creating custom UIViewController transitions easy. Although it will require some familiarity with iOS libraries and experience with animation logic.

You can check out this [article](https://www.raywenderlich.com/110536/custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions).